# error X3503: 'main_Impl': function return value missing semantics with "d2d1effecthelpers.hlsli"

Tags: shader, directx, hlsl, direct2d

I am new to HLSL and is trying to compile a simple test with [HLSL Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/hlsl-helpers) However, it doesn't compile. I want to compile shader for my Win2D UWP app.

The code:

```
#define D2D_INPUT_COUNT 1
#define D2D_INPUT0_SIMPLE
#include "d2d1effecthelpers.hlsli"

D2D_PS_ENTRY(main)
{
    float4 color1 = D2DGetInput(0);

    return color1;
}
```

When compile this with command-line :

> fxc /T ps_4_0 /E main_Impl /Fo testShader.ps testShader.hlsl

It give me this compile error

> error X3503: 'main_Impl': function return value missing semantics

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be `fxc /T ps_4_0 /D D2D_ENTRY=main /Fo testShader.ps testShader.hlsl`.

You could/should use Visual Studio, it will do the ground work for you. Or just open "d2d1effecthelpers.hlsli" and it will say this:

> // To use these helpers, the following values must be defined before
> inclusion:
>
> //   D2D_INPUT_COUNT - The number of texture inputs to the
> effect.
>
> //   D2D_INPUT[N]_SIMPLE or D2D_INPUT[N]_COMPLEX - How the
> effect will sample each input. (If unspecificed, defaults to
> _COMPLEX.)
>
> //   D2D_ENTRY - The name of the entry point being compiled. This will usually be defined on the command line at
> compilation time.